# Python - Pipenv not display in the Python interpreter

Tags: python, interpreter, pipenv, pythoninterpreter

I installed and activated pipenv in my project folder, but then I couldnt see the Pipenv in the list of Python interpreter. This is the steps I did:

- Create new project folder, cd to this folder.
- Install pipenv: pip3 install pipenv
- Activate it: pipenv shell
- Then I check the Python interpreter, but the pipenv is not in the list.

Anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance!!! Im using Mac btw.

I cannot embed the screenshot to this post, so I attach the screenshot here.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3):

Oh, I just figure the manual way to do it, sorry I am newbie so it may seems too simple for many of you haha, post here in case anyone needs it:

1. After activating pipenv (using `pipenv shell`), you will notice there're few lines in terminal informing that virtual environment has been created successfully, something like this: 
   `✔ Successfully created virtual environment!` 
   `Virtualenv location: /Users/zoey/.local/share/virtualenvs/part_manager-GqnnAfaN` 
   `Creating a Pipfile for this project...` 
   `Launching subshell in virtual environment...`
2. Open the list of Interpreter using `Command Shift P` in macOS, select `Python: Select Interpreter`
3. Select `Enter interpreter path...`
4. Paste the virtual location path in step 1 and press Enter, for e.g. in my case it is `/Users/zoey/.local/share/virtualenvs/part_manager-GqnnAfaN`
5. Done, the pipenv interpreter will be displayed accordingly in the bottom left of your Visual Studio Code.